# AS3 Flash/AIR recording video with webcam and save it

Tags: actionscript-3, video, webcam, record

Is it possible for AS3 to record a video with a webcam and save it to a local disk/to a network server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973002/save-video-captured-from-webcam-using-flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Air app called AirCam to achieve this. It uses the BitmapData class to generate a FLV file. If you want to build it yourself they also include the the source code on the site. There class does not support sound though.

> The purpose of this revolutionary new
>   class is to record a stream of
>   BitmapData to a FLV-file, because
>   writing directly, and especially the
>   converting-BitmapData-to-ByteArrays-with-byteshifting-part, made everything run shaky. I solved
>   that issue by saving the BitmapData to
>   a temporary file on the system. This
>   to protect your RAM from overloading,
>   and when done recording, the class
>   converts that temporary file to an
>   FLV-file.

http://www.joristimmerman.be/wordpress/2008/12/18/flvrecorder-record-to-flv-using-air/

Comment: Hello, AirCam does not support sound? How do you solved the shaky issue by saving it to a temp file on system?

Comment: I tested with recording a 30seconds clip and my computer hangs >_<

Comment: AirCam was just an example on how you can write a class that saves webcam data to flv. And as I wrote in my answer, it does NOT support audio recording.