# Directly upload video captured from webcam

Tags: actionscript-3, webcam, video-capture, red5

I'm working on a site, which needs to have a feature of users capturing their opinions about a specific topic with their webcam, and uploading them to the server. After a short research, and viewing similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973002/save-video-captured-from-webcam-using-flash) I ran out of possibilities:

- I cannot use Flash Media Server (out of budget)
- I cannot use Red5, as the server where the app will be hosted is not able to build or install it. (our server guy told me that Red5 was last updated in 2007, and he got some errors which I include below (in case that someone would have an idea how to fix it) )

**Are there any other possibilities?**

---

*red5 install errors:*

```
xxyyzz@zzyyxx ~/red5 $ sh red5.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/red5/server/Standalone
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.server.Standalone
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.red5.server.Standalone. Program will exit.

xxyyzz@zzyyxx ~/red5 $ ant prepare
Buildfile: /home/xxyyzz/red5/build.xml
 [echo] java.home is /usr/lib64/icedtea6/jre and the target version is 1.6

prepare:
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxyyzz/red5/bin
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxyyzz/red5/dist
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxyyzz/red5/bin/testcases
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxyyzz/red5/bin/testcases/testreports

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second

xxyyzz@zzyyxx ~/red5 $ ant build
Buildfile: /home/xxyyzz/red5/build.xml
 [echo] java.home is /usr/lib64/icedtea6/jre and the target version is 1.6

BUILD FAILED
Target "build" does not exist in the project "RED5".

Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: Really 2007? That's news to me since I just committed some code last week (2012) and have done so regularly since 2006. http://code.google.com/p/red5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for "production ready" solutions you're pretty much looking at flash media server. Other than that, try googling around for a PHP FLV encoding but I dont think you're gonna be able to stream to php and encode on the fly. Dunno, have to research and ask a PHP developer. Maybe post a modified version of this question with PHP tags.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at haxevideo, I've never used it but it could be what your after. http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid that our hosting service won't be willing to install experimental components that aren't production ready.. But thanks, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Ascension Systems - could you please add your comment as an answer? It's the best so far, even it's just a suggestion, and I'd like to accept it to close this one.

Answer (score 0):

Teo!  Have you tried to look for an online service (like Nimbb)? I used NImbb in one of my projects and it worked very well.  I didn't need to spend time in programming and the technology they offer was very use for the end-users. This is a very

Please let me know if my information helps you.