# Flash video capture and sharing

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, adobe, flex4.5

Is there any way to capture and upload video from web cam? Video upload expectation is it much smiler to Facebook video upload from web cam.

Can anybody recommend any technology to use and example application?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973002/save-video-captured-from-webcam-using-flash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use flash media server. Otherwise capture image from video container and play it as sequence. listen it is image sequence it has no sound. Correct way is using any flash media server. Ex : FMS by adobe , red 5 etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "capture image from video container"?  In addition, is this done on the client side, then I send raw frames to be reconstructed by something like ffmpeg?  or is this done on the server?