# Recording video using webcam in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am new to as3,
i know how to use a webcam in as3,i want to record webcam video and save to my Local disk
Help me 
           Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking into: http://www.joristimmerman.be/wordpress/2008/12/18/flvrecorder-record-to-flv-using-air/ (video only, no audio)

or reading this: [Save video captured from webcam using Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973002/save-video-captured-from-webcam-using-flash) .

From what I've seen though there's not much out there for recording video to your local disk via Flash. I remember looking a couple years ago for this same thing but it doesn't look like there is much that has changed since then.

Comment: Got it!!
By using Red5 Media server and Flash